# Responsive Google Visualization JavaScript Chart Library

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, google-analytics

Hi Everyone i am doing a project on Google analytic and want some help from you people.

I have made graphs of Google analytic data in Google Visualization JavaScript Library that i want to make a WordPress plugin. I have stuck to make graphs responsive. Also i am using bootstrap to make my pages responsive but the div's i have made in which i show my graphs are responsive but i failed to make my graphs responsive. So is the Google library for charts is responsive or not? Secondly i have set the width of div in which my graph lies to 100% but it does not help me. please help me to make my graphs responsive.

but it does not help me. Is there any way to make the graphs responsive. I am using Google visualization JavaScript Library.

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
     function drawChart() {
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
        ['2004',  1000,      400],
        ['2005',  1170,      460],
        ['2006',  660,       1120],
        ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      vAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>


</head>
 <body>
<div id="chart_div" style="width:'100%'; height: 500px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for make chart responsive you need to call your 'drawChart' function again from resize event.

```
<script>

    function drawChart(){
    .......chart data e.g -----
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).resize(function(){
            drawMap();
        });
    });   
</script>
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/Qquse/211/)

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in the same problem but then i realize that even if the charts don't resize while resizing the browser window they are still responsive as long as your div is responsive.

Try resizing your window to a low resolution and refresh the browser, you will see how the charts automatically fit your div correctly.

Although looking at your code i don't think your "char_div" is fully responsive, you shouldn't set a height to a pixel value if you want it to be responsive. You can either set it as 'auto' or simply set your width to '100%' without specifying the height.

Hope i could help in some way :)